# How can I implement IndexMut for a type which doesn't store the value itself

Tags: indexing, rust

I have a struct, lets call it `A` and an enum `E`.

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Clone, Copy, PartialEq, Eq)]
enum E {
    Val1,
    Val2,
    Val3,
    Val4,
}

#[derive(Debug, Clone, Copy, PartialEq, Eq)]
struct A {
    a: u64,
    b: u64,
}
```

I implemented the `Index` trait as:

```rust
impl Index<usize> for A {
    type Output = E;
    fn index(&self, index: usize) -> &Self::Output {
        match ((self.a >> index) & 1, (self.b >> index) & 1) {
            (0, 0) => &E::Val1,
            (0, 1) => &E::Val2,
            (1, 0) => &E::Val3,
            (1, 1) => &E::Val4,
            _ => unreachable!(),
        }
    }
}
```

I have a method `set_val` on `A`.

```rust
impl A {
    pub fn set_val(&mut self, idx: usize, val: E) {
        match val {
            E::Val1 => {
                self.a &= !1 << idx;
                self.b &= !1 << idx;
            }
            E::Val2 => {
                self.a &= !1 << idx;
                self.b |= 1 << idx;
            }
            E::Val3 => {
                self.a |= 1 << idx;
                self.b &= !1 << idx;
            }
            E::Val4 => {
                self.a |= 1 << idx;
                self.b |= 1 << idx;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to know how I could implement `set_val` using `IndexMut`, so that I can do:

```rust
let mut a = A {a: 0, b: 0};
a[4] = E::Val3;
// instead of
a.set_val(4, E::Val3);
```

Comment: @ÖmerErden: That will not work for this case, because `index_mut()` must return a mutable reference, but there is nothing to be returned here. The `index()` case is solved because it returns `'static` references to const enums. But a mutable will not work. I don't think it is possible to do this. I'd just write a `get/set` pair.

Comment: @rodrigo that's correct, assignment operator needs to be overloaded for this case but it's not possible.

Comment: This isn't possible. The signature of `index_mut` would have to change to be able to return a smart pointer instead of a `&mut`.

Comment: You want the (not yet designed) [`IndexSet`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/997) trait...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @rodrigo have pointed out in the comments, `IndexMut` returns a mutable reference. This way, you can do things like `&mut slice[index]` to get a mutable reference to the element at the given index, which already exists in memory.

However, you are creating and returning an instance of `E` here. Writing to that value will not update the original `a` and `b` variables. This is because once you return from `index_mut`, you no longer have access to `self`, and cannot update any variables; the caller is supposed to simply write to the mutable reference you returned, which in this case would do nothing.

As @eggyal pointed out, this might be possible with the proposed [`IndexSet` trait](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/997), which could look something like this (my idea based on [this postponed PR](https://github.com/japaric/rfcs/blob/7a32545504ab184925c0c5a123d93a2c4effb6f9/text/0000-index-assign.md#the-trait)):

```rust
trait IndexSet<Index, Rhs> {
    /// `self[index] = rhs`
    fn index_set(&mut self, index: Index, rhs: Rhs);
}
```

Then you could implement it like this, nearly identically to your `set_val` method:

```rust
impl IndexSet<usize, E> for A {
    pub fn index_set(&mut self, idx: usize, val: E) {
        match val {
            E::Val1 => {
                self.a &= !1 << idx;
                self.b &= !1 << idx;
            }
            E::Val2 => {
                self.a &= !1 << idx;
                self.b |= 1 << idx;
            }
            E::Val3 => {
                self.a |= 1 << idx;
                self.b &= !1 << idx;
            }
            E::Val4 => {
                self.a |= 1 << idx;
                self.b |= 1 << idx;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Fingers crossed that this feature will work out.

Comment: Let's hope this trait lands soon. Till then, I guess I'll have to use dedicated getter / setter methods.